# Problema con una cookie - PHP

Tags: php7, cookies, setcookie

Tengo un inconveniente al momento de realizar una comprobación del valor de una Cookie 'id_usuario': **$_COOKIE['id_user']**
Lo que me sucede es que después de crear una nueva sesión con otro usuario y al momento de comprobar esa información con la que tengo almacenada en una base de datos me sale el usuario anterior.
Por ejemplo, si inicié una sesión previa con un usuario con el id **56** y lo cierro, luego de iniciar sesión con el usuario id **60** y comprobar ese dato con el que tengo almacenado en la BD me sigue apareciendo el id de usuario **56**.

Les dejo mi código PHP:

*Fragmento en el inicio de sesión*

```
   // COOKIE USER ID
   $arr_cookie_options = array (
   // 'expires' => time() + 60*60*24*30,
   'path' => '/',
   // 'domain' => '.example.com', // leading dot for compatibility or use subdomain
   'secure' => true,     // or false
   // 'httponly' => true,    // or false
   // 'samesite' => 'None' // None || Lax  || Strict
   );

   setcookie('user_id', $id_user, $arr_cookie_options);
```

*Fragmento en la comprobación del id de usuario*

```
$id  = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
```

Comment: ¿Al salir sesión eliminas o destruyes a ```$_COOKIE['user_id']```? Porque por defecto si expire = 0, este es eliminado cuando el navegador es cerrado.

Comment: No, al salir hago claudicar la cookie con time() - 3600...

Comment: Creo que ya encontré el problema. Al parecer el problema lo tenía porque al crear la COOKIE con php le agregaba 'secure' => true . Lo cambié por false y en la consola me salía bien el 'id_user' que había agregado.

Comment: Si eso fue que te soluciono el problema, puedes publicar tu propia respuesta y aceptar lo para cerrarlo como solucionado, así puedes ayudar a otros usuarios que tengan ese mismo problema. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré el problema. Al parecer lo tenía porque al crear la COOKIE con php le agregaba 'secure' => true . Lo cambié por false y en la consola me salía bien el 'id_user' que había agregado.